# What is the duration measured in XEvent Profiler?

Tags: sql-server-profiler

I have XEvent Profiler in SQL Server 2016. Some articles say the duration is measured in microseconds or milliseconds depending on the SQL Server version.

How do I check whether it is microseconds or milliseconds?